# Вставка картинки в Java приложение

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток! Пишу программу на Java. Надо чтобы в окне отображалась картинка. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете унаследоваться от класса JPanel и, переопределив метод paintComponent() рисовать, что угодно, в том числе и картинку:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
       try {                
          image = ImageIO.read(new File("myimage.bmp"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           .....
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно в `JLabel` вывод картинки делать.